# Как SVG сконвертировать в JPG или PNG на C#?

Tags: c#, svg

Я генерирую SVG файлы на C#, необходимо используя C# отрендерить их в JPG или PNG. Как это можно сделать?

Интересны любые варианты, но ответом приму только тот который будет работать на shared хостинге, так как скрипт будет запускаться там. Хостинг ASP.NET MVC 5 - [Smarterasp](https://www.smarterasp.net).

Comment: [Convert SVG to PNG or JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254422)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Библиотека [SVG](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) для C#.

Работает так:

```
SvgDocument svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open("myFile.svg");
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = svgDoc.Draw();
bitmap.Save("outFile.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Брать надо пакет не из NuGet так как там древняя версия и много багов, а прямо горячую, придётся скачать с [github](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) и скомпилировать.

Проект рабочий, поддерживается и развивается, но как оказалось присутствуют баги, которые разработчики постепенно убирают.

Библиотека позволяет не только рендерить готовый SVG файл, но и создавать его используя свой API на лету.

Comment: Дмитрий, а как загрузить `myFile.svg` не с диска, а по `url` ?

Comment: @Vipz не думаю что там есть для этого встроенный API. Я думаю просто скачать файл из интернета любым способом, в C# для этого есть API, например WebClient, и потом направить его в эту библиотеку.

Comment: Да, так и пришлось делать, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Способ с использованием **Inkscape**.

Запускаем из командной строки такую команду

```
inkscape.exe -z "pathToSVGFile.svg" --export-png="pathToResultFile.png"
```

В данной ситуации `inskape` я прописал их в системные пути.

Как оказалось `Inkscape` не все файлы которые работают в браузере может преобразовать. Для корректной работы потребовалось атрибут `href` у `use` заменить на `xlink:href` и прописать в головном теге `svg` `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`.

### 2. Способ с использованием node.js модуля svgexport

Устанавливаем модуль [svgexport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgexport) глобально

```
npm install svgexport -g
```

Запускаем команду из консоли

```
svgexport "FileNameWithPath.svg" "ResultFileNameWithPath.png" png 100%
```

Сила этого метода в том, что `node.js svgexport` использует браузерный движок `phantom.js` для рендера, который основан на `WebKit` модуле, а это означает что результат будет наиболее соответствовать отображению в браузерах с `Chromium` основой. Кроме того получится по максимуму использовать именно браузерный синтаксис.

Минусом этого метода оказалось то, что в команде конвертации при обработке путей с русскими названиями происходит ошибка, поэтому необходимо все файлы класть в англоязычные директории.

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://mijingo.com/blog/exporting-svg-from-the-command-line-with-inkscape) и [тут](https://mijingo.com/blog/exporting-svg-from-the-command-line-with-svgexport).

**Добавлено:**

Прочитав [issue](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport/issues/47) на github понял что пути не работали скорее всего из-за наличия пробелов в пути.

Answer (score 2):

При наличии Internet Explorer 11 можно использовать COM-объекты MSHTML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
//Reference: System.Drawing
//Reference: Microsoft HTML Object Library

namespace SVG
{
    public class SvgConvert
    {        

        public static void ToPng(string svgcontent, string outpath)
        {
            RECTL rcClient = new RECTL();
            bool b = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, ref rcClient, 0);
            if (b == false) { rcClient.bottom = 480; rcClient.right = 640; }

            int width = (int)(rcClient.right - rcClient.left);
            int height = (int)(rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top);
            IntPtr screendc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);

            string svghtml =
                "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=11\" /></head><body>" + svgcontent + "</body></html>";

            mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = null;
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 d2 = null;
            IOleObject pObj = null;
            IViewObject pView = null;

            try
            {
                doc = new mshtml.HTMLDocument(); //создание документа
                d2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)doc;
                int hr;

                //установка размера документа
                pObj = (IOleObject)d2;
                SIZEL sz = new SIZEL();

                sz.x = (uint)MulDiv(width, HIMETRIC_INCH, GetDeviceCaps(screendc, LOGPIXELSX));
                sz.y = (uint)MulDiv(height, HIMETRIC_INCH, GetDeviceCaps(screendc, LOGPIXELSY));
                ;
                hr = pObj.SetExtent((int)System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT, ref sz);
                if (hr != 0) throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);

                //запись SVG в документ
                d2.write(svghtml);
                d2.close();

                //преобразование в Bitmap
                pView = (IViewObject)d2;
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                using (g)
                {

                    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                    hr = pView.Draw((int)System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT,
                        -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, hdc, ref rcClient, IntPtr.Zero,
                        IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                    if (hr != 0) throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);
                    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                }

                //сохранение в PNG
                bmp.Save(outpath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


            }
            finally
            {
                //освобождение ресурсов                
                if (d2 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(d2);
                if (pObj != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pObj);
                if (pView != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pView);
                if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int nAction, int nParam, ref RECTL rc, int nUpdate);

        public static int MulDiv(int number, int numerator, int denominator)
        {
            return (int)(((long)number * numerator) / denominator);
        }

        const int LOGPIXELSX = 88;
        const int LOGPIXELSY = 90;
        const int HIMETRIC_INCH = 2540;
        const int SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48;

    }

    [ComImport()]
    [GuidAttribute("0000010d-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IViewObject
    {
        int Draw([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwDrawAspect, int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, IntPtr ptd, IntPtr hdcTargetDev, IntPtr hdcDraw,
            ref RECTL lprcBounds, IntPtr lprcWBounds, IntPtr pfnContinue, int dwContinue);
        int a();
        int b();
        int c();
        int d();
        int e();
    }

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IOleObject
    {
        void f();
        void g();
        void SetHostNames(object szContainerApp, object szContainerObj);
        void Close(uint dwSaveOption);
        void SetMoniker(uint dwWhichMoniker, object pmk);
        void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
        void x();
        void y();
        void DoVerb(uint iVerb, uint lpmsg, object pActiveSite, uint lindex, uint hwndParent, uint lprcPosRect);
        void EnumVerbs(ref object ppEnumOleVerb);
        void Update();
        void IsUpToDate();
        void GetUserClassID(uint pClsid);
        void GetUserType(uint dwFormOfType, uint pszUserType);
        int SetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, ref SIZEL psizel);
        void GetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
        void Advise(object pAdvSink, uint pdwConnection);
        void Unadvise(uint dwConnection);
        void EnumAdvise(ref object ppenumAdvise);
        void GetMiscStatus(uint dwAspect, uint pdwStatus);
        void SetColorScheme(object pLogpal);
    };



    public struct RECTL
    {
        public uint left;
        public uint top;
        public uint right;
        public uint bottom;
    }

    public struct SIZEL
    {
        public uint x;
        public uint y;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
string svgcontent = "<svg><circle cx=\"200\" cy=\"200\" r=\"150\" stroke=\"red\" fill=\"green\" stroke-width=\"10\"/></svg>";

SvgConvert.ToPng(svgcontent,"c:\\test\\svgimage.png");
```

Источник: [Using IE to Save SVGs as Bitmaps to Wherever](http://paige-rudnick.com/2014/01/30/using-ie-to-save-svgs-as-bitmaps-to-wherever/)