# SVG в WPF, в image?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Нужно отобразить svg в WPF. Нашел видео https://youtu.be/RHZXc62YWzE  где сказано что все ок просто юзайте IMAGE... но у меня чтото не работает. Может кто сталкивался ?

Comment: Компьютер выключается, система зависат или что означает "не работает"? Дополните вопрос подробностями, покажите разметку.

Comment: [WPF What is the correct way of using SVG files as icons in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528493/312041)

Comment: Хех, очень любопытная логика, брать видео, где показывают UWP проект и пытаться применить это в древнем WPF, извиняйте, но WPF хоть и хорош, но много нового не имеет в себе (того, что есть в UWP). Ну а так, все зависит от того, какую графику вы хотите вывести, если это простая иконка с простой графикой, то досточно простого `Path` ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869660/220553)), если это что-то сложнее, многослойнет, то тут либо писать свои решения (.svg это простой xml), либо использовать сторонние.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отобразить SVG в image](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881670/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-svg-%d0%b2-image)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно видео старое, сейчас в лоб не поддерживается SVG. Есть NuGet пакет **SharpVectors**. С ним просто используете в XAML `SvgViewbox`.